# Object lagging/teleporting in simple pygame stimulation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to create a simple program that stimulates the revolution of stars in a binary system, but when I run the program, one of the 'stars' glitches around, practically teleporting around the given path to different locations. How can I fix this? Here is the code:

```
import pygame, sys, math, keyboard

run = True
black = (255, 255, 255)
white = (0, 0, 0)
angle = 0
size = width, height = 1550, 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen.fill(black)

while run:
    msElapsed = clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    def star1():
        global angle
        screen.fill(white)
        x = int(math.cos(angle) * 70) + 775
        y = int(math.sin(angle) * 100) + 400
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, black, (x, y), 10)
        pygame.display.flip()
        angle += 0.05


    def star2():
        global angle
        screen.fill(white)
        x = int(math.cos(angle) * 100) + 775
        y = int(math.sin(angle) * 70) + 400
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, black, (x, y), 10)
        pygame.display.flip()
        angle += 0.05

    star1()
    star2()

    if keyboard.is_pressed('Esc'):
        print("System Terminated ('ESC')")
        sys.exit(0)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: @anurag on codereview it would be closed as off-topic in a heartbeat. Code not working as intended is off-ttopic there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by `screen.fill(white)` and the multiple calls to [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update). The [`fill()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) function fills the entire *Surface* with a solid color. Call fill once at the begin of the application loop. An update of the display at the end of the application loop is sufficient. Multiple calls to `pygame.display.update()` or `pygame.display.flip()` cause flickering.

Remove all calls to `pygame.display.flip()` from your code, but call it once at the end of the application loop.

You don't need the `keboard` package at all. Use the [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) instead.

[image]

```py
while run:
    msElapsed = clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    def star1():
        global angle
        # screen.fill(white)                           <--- DELTE
        x = int(math.cos(angle) * 70) + 775
        y = int(math.sin(angle) * 100) + 400
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, black, (x, y), 10)
        # pygame.display.flip()                        <--- DELTE
        angle += 0.05

    def star2():
        global angle
        # screen.fill(white)                           <--- DELTE
        x = int(math.cos(angle) * 100) + 775
        y = int(math.sin(angle) * 70) + 400
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, black, (x, y), 10)
        # pygame.display.flip()                        <--- DELTE
        angle += 0.05

    screen.fill(white)                               # <--- ADD
    star1()
    star2()
    pygame.display.flip()                            # <--- ADD

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()                  # <--- CHANGE
    if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
        print("System Terminated ('ESC')")
        sys.exit(0)
```

Note, you use the same `angle` for both objects. Hence the `angle` is incremented twice in each frame.